# Alternative to C, C++?

Tags: c++, c

All,

There are so many programming languages/Operating systems/device drivers i.e. softwares that are built using [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) and [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B). I was wondering if C and C++ were the only 2 low level programming languages that all companies ever had to build their own product(s)? If there are, why do C and C++ get so much preference over other options?

Comment: Apple uses Obj-c for great parts of its OS

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language  What more do you need to know?  Why ask here?

Comment: Define "low-level programming languages"? Do you mean compiled languages vs. interpreted languages?

Comment: @pastjean: OS X kernel mode drivers are written in a subset of C++. Obj-C is mostly used for user mode stuff.

Comment: @S.Lott: I did not understand your point of posting a link on Low level programming and might be voting to close this thread. Since I have mentioned it in my post, I do know what it is. My question was of other low level languages being widely used.

Comment: @S.Lott: that article seems to me to say that the only low-level programming languages are machine code and assembler. Far be it from me to doubt the wisdom of the crowds, but that's not the sense in which programmers, typically, in this millennium, use the term. "Low" is after all a relative term.

Comment: @darkie15, @Steve Jessop.  The term is obviously vague.  The question is obviously vague.  One can either clean up the question to be less vague.  Or wait for it to be closed.  I'm pointing out the vagueness.

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid that your hint that your issue was with vagueness, was too vague for me. I thought you were suggesting that the Wikipedia article answered the question.

Comment: C, and most especially C⁺⁺, are certainly **not** ‘low-level’ programming languages!

Comment: @S.Lott: I am sorry if you found my question to be vague and thankful to many who got the gist of it.

Comment: @darkie15: "I am sorry if you found my question to be vague".  Don't apologize.  Fix The Question so that other people can understand it.  Please consider that thousands of people read this questions.  Not everyone is a genius.  Many people need help to understand the question.  You can fix it or you can apologize or you can complain.  Fixing it is best.  Please fix it.

Comment: One of the very few _true_ alternatives to C++ is [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other low-level languages, but C had the benefit of a 'popularity snowball' effect.

It's about as efficient as any reasonably portable language can be, so it's a good choice for systems programming. Once you build an operating system on it, it makes sense to build tools for the same system with it, so a lot of programmers got exposed to it in the 80s and 90s. Thus it became a *lingua franca* that all systems programmers were familiar with.

There's relatively little you can do to improve on C without compromising either its efficiency or its portability, so there was no obvious place to compete against it at the low level.

Comment: That is what I wanted to understand. There has been so much competition when it comes to web programming languages or object-oriented programming. But in case of procedural languages, for some reason, C has always been in the limelight for corporate firms.

Comment: *“There's relatively little you can do to improve on C without compromising either its efficiency or its portability, so there was no obvious place to compete against it at the low level.”*  The syntax. I'm thinking about C's "declaration reflects use" for types. It's terrible. I'd replace it with a postfix type syntax like that of Scala, Go, Haskell, or ML; e.g., `var x: int = 5;`, `var dptr: **double;`, `def sort(a: *int, len: int, cmp_lt: (int, int) -> bool): unit;`. IMO, the improvement would be immense, and the change would have *no* impact on performance or portability.

Comment: You can't point to that syntax and say it's objectively enough better than the C syntax that people should switch. Even if it was, obviously, objectively better, once C has a foothold that's not enough reason to change. Consider Esperanto vs. English, Dvorak vs. QWERTY. If that syntax could cut compilation times in half or something, then you might get people to switch.

Answer (score 7):

There are many "medium-level" languages suitable for OS development, but C and to a lesser extent C++ are by far the most popular. There are many reasons for this, including:

- The early success of C as the implementation of Unix led to its widespread adoption.
- The vast availability of great development tools (compilers, lint, editors, memory leak analysis, profiles, code generators, ad nauseam) makes C even more compelling.
- The closeness of C to the "abstract machine" level; unlike, say, Pascal, which has considerably more runtime overhead. This is desirable when writing high performance software. C has sometimes been called a "portable assembler" for its closeness to the hardware.

Comment: +1 Your first bullet is the correct answer. C = Unix, C# = Microsoft, ObjC = iPhone. The platform makes the language popular.

Comment: @jojaba: Microsoft is still C for the actual OS (AFAIK), as is the MacOSX kernel, even if upper layers are implemented on top of that with C#/ObjC

Comment: @David: Your right. And I didn't mean to imply that the OS for each respective company or technology is written in the said language, but rather that it take a popular platform to help move a language up the ladder. If Apple didn't release the iPhone, I doubt that the tag `objective-c` would be higher than the tag `c` in SO. (Pure speculation)

Answer (score 6):

Forth is sometimes used for developing low level software like device drivers. For example the boot prom for SUN SPARC based servers used to be written in Forth. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Firmware for details.

Comment: +1 I was about to post Forth :-)

Comment: It's not just SPARC by the way. I think Apple had this, as did some IBM pSeries boxes (AIX) from memory.

Comment: @paxdiablo, you are absolutely right, some Apple and IBM systems do use Open Firmware. It was on SPARC systems where I encountered it, though, so that's why it came to mind.

Comment: @pmg Have you done much work in Forth? It is a language I'd like to learn at some stage, just because it is so different. I voted for it when Bruce Tate was asking for what languages to include in his book 'Seven Languages in Seven Weeks', but unfortunately it didn't make the cut.

Comment: I have only played a bit with Forth, nothing you could call work. I guess I like the "stack based" paradigm.

Answer (score 3):

I know some people that do systems programming in [D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28programming_language%29).  It is lower level than C#, etc. but had many of the same benefits of modern languages.

Comment: D relies heavily on GC. It's hard to imagine writing low-level code with that.

Comment: Wikipedia starts, "The D programming language is an object-oriented, imperative, multi-paradigm system programming language..."  It gives much control over the GC and allows explicit freeing of memory which I would think make it appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Even more than the low level of abstraction, the key feature of C and (C++ with RTTI disabled) that is applicable to system software is that they don't need any runtime library.

See, you can write a compiler in the very same language, but you can't write a runtime in the language that depends on it.

C has a standard library but not a runtime library, so you can implement the standard library in C, and you can also use it to write the runtime libraries for other languages.  Ditto for C++ (with RTTI disabled).

Answer (score 2):

No, there are absolute bucketloads of languages that companies use to produce their software. C has a clear advantage over all of them for one particular area, that of very low-level stuff, since it imposes very little between the code and the hardware.

Most other languages (including C++ to some extent, unless you restrict yourself to the C side of it) tend to carry a lot of unnecessary baggage which, while an absolute godsend for applications programming, tend to just get in the way for systems level stuff.

Of course, you could also use assembly code but that's rarely necessary nowadays with the quality of the C compilers.

Comment: In C++ you do not need to comprise to the C subset of it. There are many features not available in C that do not impose any cost: construction and destruction (RAII), templates (they might impose a cost in memory, but not in speed), virtual functions are not worse than function pointers when needed...

Answer (score 2):

Ada, Pascal, assembly, Fortran, etc etc.  Even when you are limiting the discussion to low-level languages, you still have a lot of choices.  There are a lot of companies that don't do much C or C++ work at all (for example, the US military does a considerable amount of work using Ada).

One reason C and C++ are so popular is because so many people know those languages (I realize that's a recursive answer).  Companies use C or C++ because it is easy to find a developer who knows the language, and developers learn the language because that is what companies are hiring.  It also doesn't hurt that there is a very wide selection of books, compilers, IDEs, debuggers, libraries, etc etc for C and C++, and that C/C++ compilers are available for practically any platform you might encounter.  Plus, these languages have been around for quite a while.  Legacy C code is more likely to be maintained by a C developer than re-written in another language.  Both C and C++ are versatile, powerful languages that will continue to be used for the forseeable future.  They are far from being the *only* option, though.

Answer (score 1):

C has been the lingua-franca since the early days of Unix. There is so much existing C code, so much cultural root, that people just use the language. It's more than that: C is **so** well designed: in its simplicity, in its speed of learning, speed of compiling, speed of coding, speed of running; in its bible-like tutorial book, in the sheer amount of solid open-source code we still use and hack on today, and the list goes on. It's just a *useful* language, like no pressure-independent, gravity-independent diamond-sparkled million-dollar pen with finger-prints of angels can replace a pencil.

As for C++, it is not nearly as simple as C. On the contrary: it is arguably more complex than roughly any other language out there, in terms of grammar, dark corners, learning curve, proper modern code and other criteria. One would think this complexity would kill the language, and many in fact have been saying this for *decades*. Java was born on this premise. But here we are today, roughly thirty years after the language was born, and it's still live and kicking among the 10 most popular tags on StackOverflow. There is a number of people that are *passionate* about the language, yours-truly among them.

Granted, that doesn't explain why C++ is thriving today as a popular language. I think it's the freedom C++ gives you in supporting so many different programming paradigms. This is how C++ supports programming both as low a level as C, with that same efficiency, and as high a level as other languages, given proper helper libraries. I recommend you read [this interview with Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.technologyreview.com/InfoTech/17831/).

C and C++ certainly are not the only alternatives for low-level programming. But they are an option that is very hard to resist. The **best** option, if I may boldly suggest, if only for their solid, long history that hints they are both here to stay; and for the repertoire of solid code out there that demonstrates the things you can do with these languages. The support the existing software demands promises lots of active boards on the net, lots of hiring companies -- and all in all a live, kicking pair of languages.

Comment: If you think C is a shining example of good design, you haven't tried to teach anyone function pointer syntax recently.  (Don't get me wrong, I use C and I like it -- but it's got plenty of warts.)

Comment: @Porculus congratulations, you found an awkwardness in C's syntax. And now you know that any language has its syntactical glitches. But C is a _simple language_ nonetheless, and this reduces a lot the areas in which it can have a syntax awkwardness.

Comment: Also: yes, I still think C is a **shining** example of good language design. (You forgot the emphasis). Bjarne Stroustrup said there are two kinds of languages: those people complain about and those nobody uses. So there.

Comment: +1, well said.  Although, C's minimalistic support for string handling is historically one of the primary causes of security vulnerabilities in software.

Answer (score 0):

How about C#? Many windows applications get built using C#.

How about Perl/Python? Many applications on Windows and Linux get build using those languages.

How about D? Always a nice language to use, but it's sad it does not talk as good as I need with native C++.

Comment: OP seemed to be asking specifically about low level languages for systems and device drivers, not app languages.

Answer (score 0):

Partly because it was one of the first high level languages (after B) that was adopted on a large scale.  Languages like Java are owned by companies, which at the drop of a pin could be dropped and then you wouldnt see any updates from oracle.  There is also the fact that c and c++ translate to relatively low amounts of assembly code, which makes it much smaller and compact.

There is also, the most important philosophy of C.  You dont pay for what you dont need.  (i.e in java you have garbage collection, but if you write a program that doesnt need a garbage collector, than you have wasted resources and you pay for it is speed and efficiency.)  In C, if you need something, you make it yourself, no lost resources, much more efficient code (depending on the programmer).

Comment: `A` and `B` languages? Citation please? C came from BCPL which came from CPL. Unless you're being humorous.

Comment: http://www.livinginternet.com/i/iw_unix_c.htm  You are right that it came from that, but there were first languages called A, and one called B.  They came before C, and I am sure if I spent more time on google, you could probably find out why he called it C rather than Awesome Language (no sarcasm intended).  It is just the order of the languages names.

Comment: "The initial development of C occurred at AT&T Bell Labs between 1969 and 1973;[2] according to Ritchie, the most creative period occurred in 1972. It was named "C" because its features were derived from an earlier language called "B", which according to Ken Thompson was a stripped-down version of the BCPL programming language." From Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#Early_developments

Comment: @paxdiablo: http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html, "Ken Thompson created the B language in 1969-70; it was derived directly from Martin Richards's BCPL. Dennis Ritchie turned B into C during 1971-73". The source is authoritative. I don't know that there was an A (and if there was, if it had anything to do with that language family), but neither is Ritchie sure why "B" was called "B".

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `B` is a stripped down version of `BCPL` and that `C` is a modified version of `B`. If by `A`, do you mean `ADA`?

Comment: I recall a professor calling it A, whether that was an actual language or a shorthand.  But, I will admit I should have doubled checked A, so thank you @Steve Jessop & jojaba.